# Why does GetLastError() block my method?

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface

I'm trying to write some functions for creating a Windows message-only window for working with the clipboard. I know it's failing to create the window, but when I add the `GetLastError()` function call, the function never returns to Java. This is making it tricky to debug.

```c
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_mypackage_ClipboardHelper_initialize
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jstring arg) {

    WNDCLASSEXW wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.lpszClassName = _CC_WNDCLASSNAME;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);

    if (!RegisterClassExW(&wc)) {
        printf("failed to register window class\n");
    }

    gWindowHandle = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        _CC_WNDCLASSNAME,
        L"CC clipboard helper window",
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        HWND_MESSAGE, NULL,
        GetModuleHandleW(NULL),
        NULL);

    if (!gWindowHandle) {
        printf("failed to create window\n");
        printf(GetLastError()); //this line causes function to never return
        printf("\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return gWindowHandle;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Windows expert but the [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference says: "The return value is the calling thread's last-error code". If that is correct, then you can't just pass it into `printf` as it is not a string.

Comment: You also need to call it immediately you get the error, not after doing other things that could cause other errors. You should have `printf("failed to create window: error=%d\n", GetLastError());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is not able to continue because you passed an invalid pointer to printf. `GetLastError` returns a DWORD and it has been considered as a `char*` pointer by printf.

You can change your code like this to display the last error **code**

```
if (!gWindowHandle) {
    printf("failed to create window with error=%d\n",GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Or if you want a human readable error message you can use the FormatMessage function as explained here in MSDN : [Retrieving the Last-Error Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms680582(v=vs.85).aspx)

Also take care to call `GetLastError` just after the error happens because the last error code of your current thread can be replaced by another function. For instance in your sample code you call a `printf` before calling `GetLastError`. As we do not know the `printf` implementation, it can change the last error code.

Comment: Ugh, I'm so used to Java's `println` being overloaded to work with anything. Thanks!